# In Python, why does 04000 // 1000 return 2?

Tags: python, math, floor-division

I am trying to separate a 5 digit number into its digits using floor division followed by modulo for each digit. 
Why does 04000 // 1000 return 2?

```
>>> 04//1
4
>>> 040//10
3
>>> 0400//100
2
>>> 04000//1000
2
>>> 4//1
4
>>> 40//10
4
>>> 400//100
4
>>> 4000//1000
4
```

Comment: please elaborate the problem well and were did you find the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because octal numbers in Python 2 start with a 0.  It is really 2048 decimal.

```
>>> 04000
2048
```

Python 3 changes this behavior to use `0o` as the modifier for octal:

```
>>> 04000
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    04000
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid token
>>> 0o4000
2048
```

Comment: Thanks! So is it impossible to use an integer for my five digit data-structure? Storing it as a string and converting it seems inelegant.

Comment: @BrianFu How did you enter the integer into your program?  Internally an integer is binary.  It can be *displayed* as decimal, octal, hexadecimal, etc., but that involves converting into a string for display.  `int('04000',10)` will convert a 5-digit input string into the integer value you want.

Comment: @BrianFu: Not at all; it's perfectly possible! What's not possible is to write your integer *literals* in source code as 5 digits with a leading `0`. That doesn't mean that you can't store your data in something of type `int`.

Answer (score 1):

Well, `04000` is **octal** == `2048` (decimal)

```
 04000 // 1000 == 
  2048 // 1000 == 
     2 # integer division
```